# How can I login to a website with username and password using curl?

Tags: curl

I want to update the IP Address from my DynDNS via curl. For that i need to ping a website with my username and my password. [Here a screenshot from the login screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWRG0.png). How can i pass my credentials to this via curl?

Best greetings,
DasMoorhuhn :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it...

```bash
curl -s --user USER:PASSWORD URL
```